# Migrated question shows up attributed to nobody on the front page

Tags: bug, user-interface, migration, homepage

**TL;DR minor bug: a question's showing up on our site that's attributed to nobody at all on the front page.**

RPG Stack Exchange just now had this happen:

1. [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170051/1204) was migrated to our site, belonging to a user (“Light”) who doesn't yet have an account on our site so they show up as anonymous.
2. The question was closed as off topic since we only deal with tabletop games.
3. The question was accordingly locked and the migration was rejected.

Now the question is showing up on our front page with a timestamp but attributed to nobody, not even Community or the anonymous “Light” user.

#### The front page as I see it:

[image: the front page with the top question attributed to nobody at all]

#### The question page itself:

[image: screenshot of the question, attributed to the user Light]

#### Possible cause

The timestamp on the frontpage appears to correlate exactly to [the migration event in the post's timeline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/170051/timeline) so presumably this would happen to any migrated question, even if it wasn't closed:

[image: the post's timeline with the migration event highlighted, 42 minutes ago. every other event in the timeline is attributed to somebody, this one isn't.]

Curiously it has its attribution on the /questions page:

[image: the same question on a different questions list, attributed to the author, Light]

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the question with some more details, including that disparity. Right now it only shows up on our front page while I'm logged in and is invisible from private browsing; maybe only moderators see closed rejected migrations on there? My suspicion is this might occur with every migrated question (even ones that haven't been closed and thus regular users would see them).